# Retrieve byte array from c# webservice into Qt

Tags: c#, qt, format, arrays

I use webservice written in c# that exposes bytearray of audio file (mp3 file) that is stored in database (using entity framework).

When I retrieve it in c# and save it into file using File.WriteAllBytes() I can listen to audio (file's size is 10kB).

I need to do the same with Qt. I parse the xml and save audio byte array to QByteArray like this:

```
QByteArray bytes = readValue().toUtf8();
```

where readValue() is QStringRef and then I save it to file

```
qint64 bytesWritten = file.write(bytes);
```

File hes 14kB then and I suppose that there is some format problem but not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. In webservice I return byte array converter to hex string

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
string hexString = hex.Replace("-", "");
```

then in Qt I parse data

```
QByteArray bytes = QByteArray::fromHex(readValue().toString().toLatin1()));
```

and save it to file

```
qint64 bytesWritten = file.write(bytes);
```